# Displaing closure_tree in ActiveAdmin. How to create hierarhical view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, acts-as-tree

At minimal I want to achieve some indentation in index table. Like this:

```
+Parent
+--Child
   +--Child of Child
+--Child
```

So I create the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Section do
  config.filters = false

  index do
    column :name do |s|
      " #{ "――" * s.depth } #{s.name}"
    end
    default_actions
  end

  controller do
    def collection
      Section.some_method_to_get_things_in_right_order
    end
  end
end
```

It's need to some_method return active record relation, but I haven't succeed. And ended up with [this](https://gist.github.com/astery/6172796) hacky way.

Comment: Have you got into any advanced solution? BTW you can do plain hash tree using the method named: `hash_tree_scope`

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'll keep using code exposed in gist. If someone point here any solutions for hierarchical data representation in active admin, it will be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **sortable_tree** activeadmin plugin works for me well with closure tree.

https://github.com/zorab47/active_admin-sortable_tree

It creates a simple hierarchical and sortable view.

Just put the following in your tree model resource (app/admin/TreeModel):
(assuming Rails >4, replace <..> with your values)

```
ActiveAdmin.register TreeModel do

config.filters = false # the default filters don't work unfortunately
permit_params <YOUR_TREE_MODEL_ATTRIBUTES>

sortable tree: true,
               sorting_attribute: :<YOUR_SORT_ATTRIBUTE>,
               parent_method: :parent,
               children_method: :children,
               roots_method: :roots

index :as => :sortable do
    label :name # item content
        actions
  end

end
```